# I'm getting 404 error when trying to access REST webapp

Tags: java, rest, web-services, http-status-code-404, jersey-2.0

I'm using jersey 2.6 in tomcat 6. i get this 404 error:

`web.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>   
    <display-name>ddd</display-name>


<!-- Dichiarazione delle servlet !-->
    <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>jax-rs</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                  <param-value>it.eng.ddd.webservice</param-value>
             </init-param>
             <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
                <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
            </init-param>
       <!--  <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>it.eng.ddd.webservice.EpraxiApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>-->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet> 


    <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>jax-rs</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>   

</web-app>
```

this is the webservice class:

```
package it.eng.ddd.webservice.salvaVotazioni;
@Path("/SalvaVotazioni")
public class Service
{
@GET
@Path("/salva")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
//@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response  save(@PathParam("codiceEnte") String codiceEnte)
{
    return Response.status(200).entity("").build();
}
```

when i invoke http://appurl:8080/ddd/rest on firefox it returns HTTP Status 404 - Not Found. the tomcat log trace this:

```
INFO: 6 * Server has received a request on thread http-8080-1
6 > GET http://appurl:8080/ddd/rest
6 > accept: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
6 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
6 > accept-language: it-IT
6 > cache-control: no-cache
6 > connection: Keep-Alive
6 > cookie: JSESSIONID=97812A3F4563918431A0B8EDC43C4D2D
6 > dnt: 1
6 > host: appurl:8080
6 > user-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

2-gen-2018 16.28.14 org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 6 * Server responded with a response on thread http-8080-1
6 < 404
```

Comment: Is your application called ddd? what is the name of your war file?
You should  call your web application:
localhost:8080/webapplication/servlet/path
where webapplication.war is your web archive

Comment: ddd.war. the application responds correctly at http://appurl:8080/ddd

Comment: update complete `Service` class.

Comment: i updated my question with the service class, it is extremely simple to avoid mistakes

Comment: @arachelva No, update complete class, I have seen people doing lot of mistakes there

Comment: And what is the response from call
appurl:8080/ddd//rest/salva?codiceEnte=123

Comment: @arachelva don't forget to upvote/accept my post, if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you have following mistakes :

1. For class `Service` your package name is `it.eng.ddd.webservice.salvaVotazioni` but in `web.xml`, you have mentioned `<param-value>it.eng.ddd.webservice</param-value>`. And, that is the reason I was asking to upload complete code (I have seen people doing same mistakes)
2. I'm not sure, what exactly you are trying here

   ```
   @Path("/salva")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public Response  save(@PathParam("codiceEnte") String codiceEnte)
   ```

   You have mixed everything here, where is `PathParam` in url ????
   I think, you are trying to pass some data in through url, if that is the case then , it should be something similar

   ```
   @Path("/salva/{codiceEnte}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public Response  save(@PathParam("codiceEnte") String codiceEnte)
   ```
3. From provided log, it seems you are trying to access `http://appurl:8080/ddd/rest`, but your actual endpoint should be `http://appurl:8080/ddd/rest/SalvaVotazioni/salva/{codiceEnte}`

Here is good tutorial, to help you to understand, how to use **[`@PathParam`](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-pathparam-example/)**